# Debian: Noice on AUX devices

Tags: debian, audio

Everytime I restart my notebook, an annoying noise starts. The solution I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57810/how-to-fix-no-soundcards-found) is to execute the next command after Debian starts:

```
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

But this solution doesn't work for speakers connected to AUX port (like external speakers or headphones).

I can hear sounds (like songs or movies) but also I can hear always this annoying sound.

This is my ALSA mixer:

[image: My ALSA mixer]

Comment: Just a thought, but check your alsamixer settings.  Does anything seem out of the ordinary?  I'm going from memory here, but I believe you can change the device (or sound card) by pressing F6 to toggle over to your connected speakers or headphones.

Comment: Could be many things, either from the speakers do not supporting such a high sound, to the speakers having the wrong amplification or even hardware related problems. I had quite a sound mistery in an old PC of mine and it ended up being the metal case that was not grounded properly.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro YES!  I literally just had the same issue.  Every time I moved my mouse, the onboard sound would create a small whine.  I chalked it up to driver issues, couldn't reproduce in other distros or Windows, but went away when I scraped Wayland and went back to X.

Comment: @bgregs Interesting....good job.